# How to merge two json documents in json.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm not sure of the correct terminology as not overly knowledgeable about json. I have an existing json string/object of the following fixed format (i.e. all items are at the root level and of straightforward key/value pairs, although the number of items can vary):

```
{
  "product_id": "1777",
  "license_key": "ECHOES-SILENCE-PATIENCE-AND-GRACE",
  "valid_for": "365",
  "status": "active",
  "times_activated_max": 1
}
```

I need a way to add a json string of varying schema/format that is passed into a method. This object can be of any json format. It's to be added to the root. For example adding this:

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]
}
```

..will become this:

```
{
  "product_id": "1777",
  "license_key": "ECHOES-SILENCE-PATIENCE-AND-GRACE",
  "valid_for": "365",
  "status": "active",
  "times_activated_max": 1
  "name":"John",
  "age":30,
  "cars":["Ford", "BMW", "Fiat"]
}
```

I have Newtonsoft.Json at my disposal for this.

I did read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45992994/how-to-merge-two-json-objects-using-json-net) but couldn't map it to my problem.

Hope someone can help

Comment: Why not? That's the actual answer. What you posted is two *objects*. You're asking how to merge the properties of two objects into a new one. A JSON document may be text, but what it contains are arrays and objects. "Merging" means finding a way to combine those objects/arrays and produce a new array or object.

Comment: How about reading [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm)?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Merge two JTokens into one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37756656/3744182) and/or [How can I merge two JObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21160337/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JSON.NET documentation has an article just for that: [Merging JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm). You can use `JObject.Merge` to merge two different objects into one:

```
JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'FirstName': 'John',
  'LastName': 'Smith',
  'Enabled': false,
  'Roles': [ 'User' ]
}");
JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'Enabled': true,
  'Roles': [ 'User', 'Admin' ]
}");

o1.Merge(o2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    // union array values together to avoid duplicates
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
});
```

What you posted is two objects.  A JSON document may be text, but what it contains are arrays and objects. "Merging" means finding a way to combine those objects/arrays and produce a new array or object.

[Merge](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Merge.htm) is defined by [JContainer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer.htm), the parent of both JObject and JArray. This means you can use `Merge` to merge both arrays and objects.

Another option with arrays is to use `Enumerable.Union` to combine the contents of both arrays, and create a new one :

```
var array1= JArray.Parse("[1,2,3]");
var array2= JArray.Parse("[3,4,5, \"a\"]");

var array3=new JArray(array1.Union(array2));
```

This returns `[1,2,3,4,5,"a"]`

Comment: Is there anyway to write our own merger compare function?  We have a list of complex objects we are merging, but we only care about the `Id' of them.  Not the index position?

Answer (score 3):

Json.net uses the [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) type to represent arbitrary JSON objects. This has a handy [`Merge`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Merge.htm) method for combining two JObjects.

Simply:

```
string s1 = @"
{
  ""product_id"": ""1777"",
  ""license_key"": ""ECHOES-SILENCE-PATIENCE-AND-GRACE"",
  ""valid_for"": ""365"",
  ""status"": ""active"",
  ""times_activated_max"": 1
}";
string s2 = @"
{
  ""name"":""John"",
  ""age"":30,
  ""cars"":[""Ford"", ""BMW"", ""Fiat""]
}";

JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(s1);
JObject o2 = JObject.Parse(s2);

o1.Merge(o2);

Console.WriteLine(o1);
```

[See it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zkDw8c)